# Download Permission Denied while using Wubi

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

I am trying to download Ubuntu with the Windows Installer. I had no problems last week. But this week after the download and extraction of files is complete I get a permission denied error message.  Can anybody help?

Comment: @RobinJ: If you post your answer as answer, it can be upvoted and accepted. As comment, the question might stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using the "Windows Installer", aka "Wubi". It generally causes a lot of problems. If you still want to use the "Windows Installer" in stead of the normal way, just try running it as administrator.

Basically, to solve this problem efficiently, we need more information.
Does anyone know whether Wubi stores a log file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what is causing this error. If your machine is under the control of someone else (ie, it's part of a Windows domain) then changes to your configuration may have been made. Or the installer may be trying to overwrite a file that another process has open.

If you have the rights to run them, the Sysinternals suite of tools (specifically [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)) will provide you with the means to determine with more clarity which attempted resource access is causing the permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use offline installation.

### Here is how to do that:

1. Download the ISO
2. Disconnect the internet
3. Create a folder on desktop. Name it "Ubuntu Setup"
4. Put the ISO and Wubi.exe into the folder "Ubuntu Setup"
5. Run Wubi (Double click it man) [Wubi will automatically detect the ISO and present you the Installation Wizard.]

---